# Kotlin reified generics does not keep the type as planned

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I am creating a `TypeToken`-like system similar to what Gson has and I have stumbled upon something I do not understand.

The intention with this code would be to have only one `TypeReference` class with one generic argument that could hold multiple ones. The class would be created using `inline` function, this way the user does not need to know of the `Holder` class.

Please consider the code below:

```
package testing

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
import java.lang.reflect.Type

abstract class TypeReference<T : Holder> {
    val type: Type = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]

    override fun toString(): String {
        return type.typeName
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Holder> create() = object : TypeReference<T>() {}

inline fun <reified WHAT> createSingle() = object : TypeReference<Single<WHAT>>() {}

class Foo

interface Holder

interface Single<T> : Holder

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(create<Single<HashMap<Int, String>>>())
    println(create<Single<Foo>>())

    println(createSingle<HashMap<Int, String>>())
    println(createSingle<Foo>())
}
```

This is the output:

```
testing.Single<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>>
testing.Single<testing.Foo>
testing.Single<WHAT>
testing.Single<WHAT>
```

It looks like to me as if the `Single<WHAT>` (sry for that generic name) does not get 'truly' inlined and some intermediate name gets generated.

I have also looked in the [docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/reified-type-parameters.md) but I did not find examples regarding this.

How can I create what I initially intended to do? Why does this happen?

Edit.:

I wanted to create an issue, but they already know about this.

A very similar issue is issued [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-24888#tab=Linked%20Issues) which is said to be a duplicated of [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-19452). You can also vote in the latter link.

For future reference: `Kotlin 1.2.50` is used here.

Comment: You should fix your question. You have a `Foo` class that suddenly shows up as `TestClass`.

Comment: Yes, right. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Curiously, at https://try.kotlinlang.org, `create` runs but `createSingle` throws an "Access control exception due to security reasons in web playground"

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It's easy to reproduce locally, just add `System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManager())` at the top. It fails in `TypeReference.<init>`.

Comment: I suggest reporting a bug if you didn't yet. Especially given @tiiime's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decompile this code,found some different between two func

```
private static final TypeReference create() {
  Intrinsics.needClassReification();                 <---- here
  return (TypeReference)(new TypeReference() {
  });
}

private static final TypeReference createSingle() {
  return (TypeReference)(new TypeReference() {
  });
}
```

And manual add this code, work fine. Don't known too much about this, no document found.

```
inline fun <reified WHAT > createSingle() = Intrinsics.needClassReification().let {
    object : TypeReference<Single<WHAT>>() {}
}
```

**result**:

```
Single<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>>

Single<Foo>

Single<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>>

Single<Foo>
```